# How can one find $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi_X(t)$ when $\phi_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-x^2/2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

I'm not sure why $\phi_X'(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(tx) x e^{-x^2/2}dx$ when we have $\phi_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tx) e^{-x^2/2}dx$.

(This is part of a Lemma en route to the Central Limit Theorem. Didn't think I'd get hung up on differentiation.)

Comment: $\cos(tx)\,e^{-x^2/2}$ belongs to the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and differentiation under the integral sign applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate under the integral sign here to obtain $\phi_X'(t)$ because of the following reasons:

$(i) \cos(tx)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \text{is integrable}$

$(ii) \text{The derivative of the function w.r.t 't' exists  everywhere}$

$(iii)\text{The derivative is bounded by an integrable function }$